# php form with multiple file upload capability

Tags: php, forms, file-upload

I'm trying to adapt a php form i have found called "fns". It uses before the page loads

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once('parts-request-fns.php'); 
$_SESSION['myForm'] = $_POST;

?>
```

and where i want the form to appear

```
<?php
            // contact form
            if (isset($_POST['submitted']) && ('true' == $_POST['submitted'])) { 
                // checks if the form is submitted and then processes it
                process_form(); 

            } else { 
                // else prints the form
                print_form(); 
            }

            ?>
```

the parts-request-fns.php which is referenced look as follows.. I need 3 file upload fields so my question is how would i adapt the code to allow for all 3 files to be posted? Currently each file can be sent to the form but only the first one is posted. I have changed the input id, name to second-attachment and third-attachment but not sure how to reference this further on.

```
    <?php
//start session
session_start();

// prints form
function print_form(){
?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER[’PHP_SELF’];?>" id="uploadform" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    padding: 14px 0 14px 0;
    font-weight: lighter;
    line-height: 20px;">

    <br />

  <input type="hidden" name="parts-request" id="parts-request" value="OandH "> 

    <h3>Vehicle Details</h3>

    <p style="margin:17px 0">  <label style=" font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">Vehicle Registration: <span style="color:red">*</span></label>
<input class="form-input" name="vehiclereg" id="vehiclereg" type="text" value="<?= $_SESSION['myForm']['vehiclereg']; ?>" tabindex="1" style="width:100%;"/></p>

    <p style="margin:17px 0">  <label style=" font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">VIN/Chassis Number (Last 6 Digits):</label>
<input class="form-input" name="chassisnumber" id="chassisnumber" type="text" value="<?= $_SESSION['myForm']['chassisnumber']; ?>" tabindex="1" style="width:100%;"/></p>




  <h3>Customer Details</h3>
<p style="margin:17px 0">  <label style=" font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">Name: <span style="color:red">*</span></label>
<input class="form-input" name="namefrom" id="namefrom" type="text" value="<?= $_SESSION['myForm']['namefrom']; ?>" tabindex="1" style="width:100%;"/></p>

<!--changed these-->
<p style="margin:17px 0">  <label style=" font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">Address:</label>
<input class="form-input" name="address" id="address" type="text" value="<?= $_SESSION['myForm']['address']; ?>" tabindex="1" style="width:100%;"/></p>

<p style="margin:17px 0">  <label style=" font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">Town:</label>
<input class="form-input" name="town" id="town" type="text" value="<?= $_SESSION['myForm']['town']; ?>" tabindex="1" style="width:100%;"/></p>

<p style="margin:17px 0">  <label style=" font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">Postcode:</label>
<input class="form-input" name="postcode" id="postcode" type="text" value="<?= $_SESSION['myForm']['postcode']; ?>" tabindex="1" style="width:100%;"/></p>
<!--changed these-->


<p style="margin:17px 0">  <label style=" font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">Email: <span style="color:red">*</span></label>
<input class="form-input" name="emailfrom" id="emailfrom" type="text" value="<?= $_SESSION['myForm']['emailfrom']; ?>" tabindex="3" style="width:100%;"/></p>



<p style="margin:17px 0">  <label style="margin-right: 4px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">Contact No: <span style="color:red">*</span></label>
<input type="text" class="form-input" name="contactnumber" id="contactnumber" rows="2" cols="22" tabindex="6" value="<?= $_SESSION['myForm']['contactnumber']; ?>" style="width:100%;" /></p>

<p style="margin:17px 0">  <label style="margin-right: 4px; vertical-align:top; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; ">Brief Description of Request: </label>
<textarea class="form-input" name="comments" id="comments" rows="7" cols="22" tabindex="6" value="<?= $_SESSION['myForm']['comments']; ?>" style="height:50px; width:100%;" ></textarea></p>
<p>If appropriate, please upload any photos or documents</p>
<p>Please make sure each image does not exceed 1mb in size.</p>
<p style="margin:17px 0">
<label style="margin-right: 4px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">Vehicle image/doc one:</label>
<input name="attachment" id="attachment" type="file" tabindex="7"></p>

<p style="margin:17px 0">
<label style="margin-right: 4px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">Vehicle image/doc two:</label>
<input name="second-attachment" id="second-attachment" type="file" tabindex="7"></p>

<p style="margin:17px 0">
<label style="margin-right: 4px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">Vehicle image/doc three:</label>
<input name="third-attachment" id="third-attachment" type="file" tabindex="7"></p>


<!--<div class="clear:both">
<input type="checkbox" name="agree" value="Yes, I agree for photo to be shared on facebook">I am willing for my photo to appear on facebook.</div>-->


  <!-- <input style="margin:55px 0 0 10px"class="submit-button" type="image" value="POST ME" id="submit" src="images/enter.jpg"  width="165" alt="submit"> -->

  <input type="submit" class="submit-button" type="image" value="SUBMIT" id="submit" alt="submit">

<input type="hidden" name="submitted"  value="true" />
</form>




<?php
}

// enquiry form validation

function process_form() {
    // Read POST request params into global vars
    // FILL IN YOUR EMAIL
    $to = "paul@thedesignbank.co.uk";
    $subject = trim($_POST['namefrom']);
    $vehiclereg = trim($_POST['vehiclereg']);
    $chassisnumber = trim($_POST['chassisnumber']); 
    $contactnumber = trim($_POST['contactnumber']);
    $emailfrom = trim($_POST['emailfrom']);
    $address = trim($_POST['address']);
    $town = trim($_POST['town']);
    $postcode = trim($_POST['postcode']);
    $comments = trim($_POST['comments']);

    // Allowed file types. add file extensions WITHOUT the dot.
    $allowtypes=array("jpg", "JPG", "doc", "pdf", "docx", "png", "PNG", "gif", "GIF");

    // Require a file to be attached: false = Do not allow attachments true = allow only 1 file to be attached
    $requirefile="true";

    // Maximum file size for attachments in KB NOT Bytes for simplicity. MAKE SURE your php.ini can handel it,
    // post_max_size, upload_max_filesize, file_uploads, max_execution_time!
    // 2048kb = 2MB,       1024kb = 1MB,     512kb = 1/2MB etc..
    $max_file_size="5000";

    // Thank you message
    $thanksmessage="<h2 style='font-size:18px; font-family:'arial', helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight:bold; padding-bottom:8px'>Your message have been received! <br /> </h2>";

    $errors = array(); //Initialize error array

            //checks for vehicle registation number 
        if (empty($_POST['vehiclereg']) ) {
        $errors[]='You forgot to enter your vehicle registration number';
        }

    //checks for a name
    if (empty($_POST['namefrom']) ) {
        $errors[]='You forgot to enter your name';
        }


    //checks for an email
    if (empty($_POST['emailfrom']) ) {
        $errors[]='You forgot to enter your email';
        } else {

        if (!eregi ('^[[:alnum:]][a-z0-9_\.\-]*@[a-z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$', stripslashes(trim($_POST['emailfrom'])))) {
            $errors[]='Please enter a valid email address';
        } // if eregi
    } // if empty email

            //checks for contact number 
        if (empty($_POST['contactnumber']) ) {
        $errors[]='You forgot to enter your telephone number';
        }

    //checks for a message


    // checks for required file
    // http://amiworks.co.in/talk/handling-file-uploads-in-php/
    if($requirefile=="false") {
        if($_FILES['attachment']['error']==4) {
            $errors[]='You forgot to attach your Picture';
        }
    }

    //checks attachment file
    // checks that we have a file
    if((!empty($_FILES["attachment"])) && ($_FILES['attachment']['error'] == 0)) {
            // basename -- Returns filename component of path
            $filename = basename($_FILES['attachment']['name']);
            $ext = substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.') + 1);
            $filesize=$_FILES['attachment']['size'];
            $max_bytes=$max_file_size*5000;

            //Check if the file type uploaded is a valid file type. 
            if (!in_array($ext, $allowtypes)) {
                $errors[]="Invalid file format<br /><strong>".$filename."</strong>";

        // check the size of each file
        } elseif($filesize > $max_bytes) {
                $errors[]= "Your file: <strong>".$filename."</strong> is to big. Max file size is ".$max_file_size."kb.";
            }

    } // if !empty FILES

    if (empty($errors)) { //If everything is OK

        // send an email
        // Obtain file upload vars
        $fileatt      = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'];
        $fileatt_type = $_FILES['attachment']['type'];
        $fileatt_name = $_FILES['attachment']['name'];


        // Headers
        $headers = "From: $emailfrom";

        // create a boundary string. It must be unique
          $semi_rand = md5(time());
          $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

          // Add the headers for a file attachment
          $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
                      "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
                      " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

          // Add a multipart boundary above the plain message
          $message ="This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n";
          $message.="--{$mime_boundary}\n";
          $message.="Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n";
          $message.="Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";
          $message.="From: ".$subject."\n";
          $message.="Email: ".$emailfrom."\n";

          $message.="Vehicle Registration: ".$vehiclereg."\n";
          $message.="Chassis Number: ".$chassisnumber."\n";

          $message.="Address: ".$address."\n";
          $message.="Town: ".$town."\n";
          $message.="Postcode: ".$postcode."\n";
          $message.="Contact Number: ".$contactnumber."\n";
          $message.="Comment: ".$comments."\n\n";

        if (is_uploaded_file($fileatt)) {
          // Read the file to be attached ('rb' = read binary)
          $file = fopen($fileatt,'rb');
          $data = fread($file,filesize($fileatt));
          fclose($file);

          // Base64 encode the file data
          $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));

          // Add file attachment to the message
          $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
                      "Content-Type: {$fileatt_type};\n" .
                      " name=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
                      //"Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
                      //" filename=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
                      "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
                      $data . "\n\n" .
                      "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";
        }


        // Send the completed message

        $envs = array("HTTP_USER_AGENT", "REMOTE_ADDR", "REMOTE_HOST");
        foreach ($envs as $env)
        $message .= "$env: $_SERVER[$env]\n";

        if(!mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)) {
            exit("Mail could not be sent. Sorry! An error has occurred, please report this to the website administrator.\n");
        } else {
            echo '<div id="formfeedback"><br/><h1>Thank You!</h1>'. $thanksmessage .'</p></div>';
        } // end of if !mail

    } else { //report the errors
        echo '<div id="formfeedback"><strong>Error!</strong><br />';
        foreach ($errors as $msg) { //prints each error
                echo " - $msg<br />\n";
            } // end of foreach
        echo '</p><p>Please try again</p></div>';
        print_form();
    } //end of if(empty($errors))

    } // end of process_form()
    ?>
```

Comment: Stand outside the box and see what this does `$_SESSION['myForm'] = $_POST;`

Answer (score 1):

files are passed to php in the `$_FILES`  variable and not the `$_POST` variable. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

you can move the files using the `move_uploaded_file()` function.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to upload multiple files simultaneously and have the information organized automatically in arrays for you. To do so, you need to use the same array submission syntax in the HTML form as you do with multiple selects and checkboxes:

```
    <form action="file-upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      Send these files:<br />
      <input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br />
      <input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br />
      <input type="submit" value="Send files" />
    </form>
```

and u can access form data like this :

```
$_FILES['userfile']['name'][0] , $_FILES['userfile']['name'][1]....
```

Ref link : http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php